# Minishift requires me to be a member of the Hyper-V Administrators Group, yet Local Users and Groups is not an option in computer management

Tags: windows, openshift, minishift

I need to get minishift working, yet when I attempt to run "minishift start --hyperv-virtual-switch "External VM Switch"", I am told I need to be a member of the Hyper-V Administrators group.  I looked up how to add myself to this group, but The "Local Users and Groups" tab is not available in my "Computer Management."  I tried to run "lusrmgr.msc," and I get an error telling me that this snapin is not available in my version of Windows 10.  How can I add myself to this group another way?

[image: Command Prompt]

[image: lusrmgr.msc]

Answer (score 0):

There is this [article](https://www.wincope.com/how-to-add-user-to-local-administrator-group-in-windows-10.html) about multiple options on how to add a user to the group in windows. Using cli should do the job.

In short: Open cmd as an administrator, and call something like `net localgroup "Hyper-V Administrators" user_name /add`.